# Calculate local clustering coefficient of a vertex (node) with R (by hand)

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, igraph, graph-theory

[image: local clustering coefficient by hand]

I found an example showing how to calculate LCC by hand (see image).

How can I replicate these steps in R? Focus is on finding the "Actual number of links among Neighbors" (middle step)

I would preferably have to calculate it by hand

*Does the igraph package provide this number?

Example adjacency matrix:

```
matrix(data = c(0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0), ncol = 4)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of this can be done in `igraph`. It is nice that you gave an example,
but since the graph is fully connected, all vertices have LCC=1. I decided
to use a somewhat more complicated graph. I will go through the "by hand"
part in detail for vertex 1.

**Sample graph**

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(1234)
g = erdos.renyi.game(5, 0.7)
LO = matrix(c(0,2,1,1,1,0,0,-1,1,0), nrow=5, ncol=2)
plot(g, layout=LO)
```

[image: Sample Graph]

To start with, yes, igraph has a built-in function `transitivity` for LCC. 
For my sample graph, you can get this with

```
transitivity(g, type="localundirected")
[1] 0.6666667 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.6666667
```

But the main part of your question is the hand computation. 
The only things that you need from the graph are the first 
two steps - the **Degree Centrality** and the **Actual Links Among Neighbors**.

**Degree Centrality** is given by the `degree` function

```
degree(g)
[1] 3 2 3 3 3
degree(g, 1)        ## Vertex 1 only
[1] 3
```

As you suggested in your question, the only challenging part is the 
**Actual Links Among Neighbors**. You can get this by taking the subgraph 
induced by the neighbors of a point and then checking the number of edges. 
So for vertex 1 we get

```
ecount(induced_subgraph(g, neighbors(g, 1)))
[1] 2
```

Here is the full computation for vertex 1

```
(DC   = degree(g, 1))
[1] 3
>(ALAN = ecount(induced_subgraph(g, neighbors(g, 1))))
[1] 2
(MaxPoss = DC*(DC-1)/2)
[1] 3
(LCC = ALAN/MaxPoss)
[1] 0.6666667
```

which agrees with `transitivity` given above.