# Finding degree (centrality) of all nodes from an asymmetric (directed) adjacency matrix with R

Tags: r, igraph, graph-theory

[image: network]

I have an example of a simple network represented as an adjacency matrix.

I am trying to find the degree of each node/vertex (person)

As defined, the degree of a node is the number of connections it has to other nodes. By convention, in a directed (i.e. asymmetric) matrix, the sender of a tie is the row and the target of the tie is the column.

The adjacency matrix (with 1's on the diagonal):

```
matrix(c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1), ncol = 4)
```

The result should be:

Bob: 2
Carol: 2
Ted: 3
Alice: 1

I tried to solve this writing a function, but it does not give a correct result (Carol = 1, not 2)

```
degree_centralty <- function(x) rowSums(x != 0)-1
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: From the answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53981547/calculate-local-clustering-coefficient-of-a-vertex-node-with-r-by-hand): "Degree Centrality is given by the `degree` function"

Comment: I am aware of the degree function. But I have to program this "by hand". Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `rowSums` or `colSums` you would count only one kind of connection. What you want is the union of the two and that can be found as follows:

```
degree_centralty <- function(x) rowSums(x + t(x) != 0) - 1
degree_centralty(A)
# [1] 2 2 3 1
```

where now `x + t(x)` is a symmetric matrix.